# Use jQuery Form Wizard with radio button groups required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm using jQuery Form Wizard (http://www.thecodemine.org/) to turn a form into an wizard. I have five pages, each with around four radio buttons. Each page has to have at least one radio button checked, otherwise I don't want the wizard to be able to Submit.

jQuery Form Wizard has an method for required, but it's not for radio buttons. Is it possible to group them or something? Or use another required method?

Working demo: http://suitunion.danielholm.se/customize/customize.php?type=suit&pid=38&vid=53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was really quite easy. jQuery form did resolve the radio button groups as well. Just add validation to your form script, and add your required radio button names and the message you want shown.

Example: Your radio button group includes input type radio, and all with the name="attributes". Also everyone of them need the class "required".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#measure").formwizard({
            validationEnabled:true,
            focusFirstInput:true,
            validationOptions : {
                rules: {
                    attributes: "required",
            },
                messages: {
                    attributes: "Please choose attribute of the lapel options.",
                }
            }
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```